# mySQL - How to autogenerate field values

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains thousands of URLs. Each URL will have a corresponding folder, so I was considering using mySQL to create a short and usable folder name for each existing URL and for new URLs as they are added to the table.

What I would like is to specify something like a field 5 chars long of chars a-z, and have mySQL autogenerate values for that field.

Can the mySQL engine do this natively, or would I have to do this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an auto-generated long/bigint ID and convert it after all from/to base 36 or 64.

Comment: +1: integers take less space, 5 a-z characters isn't going to be human readable in most iterations, and AUTO_INCREMENT provides a unique value vs having to roll your own & maintain it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to be able to easily determine the URL the folder name is associated with, you might find that using a UUID will provide you with a suitable way.

```
INSERT INTO t (`url`, `uuid`) VALUES('http://www.example.com/', UUID());
```

Other mechanisms along the same line include using MD5() and SHA1()

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/other-functions.html

Note that these are going to be longer than 5 chars that you mentioned, though it's possible you'll need more than that to allow sufficient space.